# Finding occurrence of words after a specified word

Tags: python, dictionary

For each word that follows every word in the input file, we want our program to tell us how many times that word follows it.  In case the word is at the end of the input file, the first word is the word that follows it.

The following code:

```
def word_cond_dictionary():
    File = open('input.txt','r').readline()
    words = File.split(",")
    dic = {}
    for i,val in enumerate(words):
        if val in dic:
            if words[i+1] in dic[val]:
                dic[val][words[i+1]] +=1
            else:
                dic[val][words[i+1]] = 1
        else:
            dic[val] = {words[0]:1}
    print(dic)
```

with input file like this:

```
red,blue,blue,red,red,green
```

prints following output:

```
{'blue': {'red': 2}, 'green': {'red': 1}, 'red': {'green': 1, 'red': 2}}
```

but our output should be:

```
{'blue': {'red': 1, 'blue': 1}, 'green': {'red': 1}, 'red': {'green': 1, 'red': 1, 'blue: 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all word pairs in a list easily

```
words = ["red","blue","red","red","blue","red","green","blue","red"]
from collections import Counter
print Counter(zip(words,words[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the Bag of Words model.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model

given

Given a string with the entire contents of your file, you can find the index of the first word under consideration with the `find` function. For example,

`text.find('red')`

Once you've found that index you can tokenize on comma's with the `split` function.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution to that problem. I had a very similar issue to struggle with. It prints correct output.

```
f = open ('example.txt').readline()
line = f.translate(None, string.punctuation).lower().split()

myDict = {}

for k, val in list(enumerate(line)):
    if k+1 < len(line):
        if val in myDict:
            if line[k+1] in myDict[val]:
                myDict[val][line[k]] += 1
            else:
                myDict[val][line[k+1]] = 1
        else:
            myDict[val] = {line[k+1]:1}
print myDict
```